# How would I generalize multiple adjacent polygons?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geolocation, geometry, geospatial

When you have a table with a Geometry type field (or Geography), you can call the `Reduce()` function to have the shapes reduced in number of vertices. Works very nicely. However, when sevral of the polygons are adjacent (they share parts of their borders), the reduced polygons do not necessarily do so.

### Example

The SQL batch:

```
CREATE TABLE #Shapes (
shape geometry,
naam varchar(50)
 )

-- exact:
insert into #Shapes (naam, shape) VALUES ('Area A',Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((52.084744368912652 5.1304192959796637, 52.085234231548384 5.1304194002877921, 52.085474282948049 5.1304486630822, 52.0857341082301 5.1304792705923319, 52.086134375073016 5.1306082883384079, 52.086594087770209 5.13079824927263, 52.087194303050637 5.1311187236569822, 52.089074697112665 5.1323992793913931, 52.089834430487826 5.1333390253130347, 52.090353938518092 5.1341692635323852, 52.090254480473 5.1342997345712416, 52.090824429301414 5.13520842681262, 52.09141399711384 5.1360295349486274, 52.091884278226644 5.1365492835175246, 52.092085719574243 5.1367767199408263, 52.092194211203605 5.1368992186617106, 52.092494247804545 5.1372492032188495, 52.092884057915427 5.13754907634854, 52.093083867570385 5.137679290259257, 52.093254011290028 5.1378082139755827, 52.093554640188813 5.1380093733314425, 52.094204571098089 5.1384683684445918, 52.094214495038614 5.1384888619650155, 52.093702809136488 5.1390791568504124, 52.0939114689827 5.1395669728517532, 52.0938675517682 5.1396009074524045, 52.093849835848111 5.1396084928439114, 52.093797143315896 5.1396473892964423, 52.093789743114428 5.1396500989447063, 52.093731224210721 5.13969055645838, 52.093728204024956 5.1396938753314316, 52.093717452138662 5.1397007238119841, 52.09355255169794 5.139717671321705, 52.093311328208074 5.1395945930853486, 52.093306955655407 5.1395602072316251, 52.093115365831181 5.1400826557073742, 52.093052050564438 5.1401469679549336, 52.092979203676805 5.1401289247442037, 52.092756105586886 5.1398569964803755, 52.092737412561 5.1397823067194368, 52.09235419591127 5.1398883965623128, 52.092214386788811 5.1400686172528616, 52.092164272349919 5.1401695687556135, 52.09208471653983 5.1403786691371351, 52.0920239102561 5.1405293103307486, 52.091924546519294 5.1407297900877893, 52.091534494888037 5.1407990844454616, 52.091654436912947 5.1401591910829172, 52.091713753540262 5.1397284107361845, 52.091763769509271 5.1391488309018314, 52.091774359305148 5.1390583129178058, 52.09170373348757 5.1383788494901648, 52.0907391263172 5.1386201300192624, 52.090711282333359 5.1385075189173222, 52.090718721970916 5.1384486802853644, 52.090745792724192 5.1383893731981516, 52.090758387919244 5.1383728119598793, 52.090776969445869 5.1383237342815846, 52.090780415022657 5.1383173598065737, 52.090745287947357 5.1382717578671873, 52.090742629869759 5.1382662602414895, 52.090704807080328 5.1382211977615952, 52.0906867091544 5.1381677808240056, 52.090701617482885 5.1380081428639635, 52.090564404382455 5.138029116065514, 52.09062412660569 5.1386488282587379, 52.090704361908138 5.1396187201607972, 52.09069472597912 5.1397384563460946, 52.090674098813906 5.1398086878471076, 52.090624484543433 5.1397491229489587, 52.090589968811038 5.1397359627815975, 52.090441891923547 5.140045978827402, 52.090305342804641 5.1400443047750741, 52.0902322656475 5.139729289803654, 52.090199632104486 5.1394877941347659, 52.090188750764355 5.1393666968215257, 52.0902532400633 5.1393868076773792, 52.09003754449077 5.1387802169192582, 52.090024582457204 5.1386965749382565, 52.090020758565515 5.1386840578634292, 52.0900124781623 5.1386172670806785, 52.090003480669111 5.1385827830526978, 52.08999918546494 5.1385372205978728, 52.089985796017572 5.1384773049503565, 52.089996868744493 5.1384535257238895, 52.090046249330044 5.138385351980105, 52.090212456043091 5.1382693609882955, 52.090183896290647 5.1379786310671935, 52.090166853580648 5.1378115779987894, 52.0899735938292 5.137785307597369, 52.089885840192437 5.1377143466379493, 52.08985487697646 5.137671007309109, 52.089845903217793 5.1376524229999632, 52.089844238944352 5.1376464897766709, 52.089850628050044 5.1375868958421052, 52.089852778393364 5.137576853302618, 52.089863699774533 5.1374888862706634, 52.089867451693863 5.1373642447870225, 52.089883847394958 5.1373361134901643, 52.089941705111414 5.1372730266302824, 52.090002277167514 5.1372403032146394, 52.090108146462811 5.1372361269295483, 52.09006458793673 5.1368091938053615, 52.089683820260689 5.1369396857917309, 52.089193989204269 5.1364887236994123, 52.088854428613558 5.1373995044268668, 52.088474480202422 5.1383894786704332, 52.088474343996495 5.1383894337341189, 52.088464433038652 5.1383690948872287, 52.088414154422111 5.13834898790222, 52.088394471909851 5.1383694768883288, 52.0883943233639 5.1383694719988853, 52.08832395415709 5.1382487505018526, 52.087933741509914 5.1377592226490378, 52.087544413445592 5.1372594955892383, 52.087484167695806 5.1372292107739481, 52.087364645209163 5.1372284211684018, 52.0869538753575 5.1372190437554366, 52.085683952551335 5.1372596949804574, 52.085304662585258 5.137269108556211, 52.085084051657141 5.1370588609653955, 52.084904317976907 5.137469710316509, 52.084444417446747 5.1384497439414369, 52.084454428168293 5.1385195698547266, 52.084484005579725 5.1385092278942466, 52.084537888644263 5.1385357407853007, 52.084511198022149 5.1389506391238067, 52.084534639492631 5.1391157133039087, 52.084215438459069 5.139372929232195, 52.084103818604156 5.1389697602953825, 52.083964082412422 5.1391396226827055, 52.083963935496286 5.139139630831778, 52.083883681101725 5.1390291205607355, 52.083994359437455 5.1386593720505784, 52.084013982437057 5.1385892418004318, 52.084053878448593 5.1383293403318735, 52.084054407430678 5.1377297231794907, 52.084053982747719 5.1375283871311694, 52.084063940448686 5.1371387927792966, 52.084070490673184 5.13703247718513, 52.084070608951151 5.1370323959272355, 52.084217049471441 5.1370617711960529, 52.0842700656977 5.1370595147110754, 52.084318579515468 5.1370449147663777, 52.084365648221834 5.137017846536426, 52.084410294202549 5.1369791406907863, 52.084451525192954 5.1369308069453, 52.084497402298688 5.1368615722581685, 52.084511263761669 5.1368357082828879, 52.084539652187722 5.1367929205345337, 52.084559679031372 5.1367565956898034, 52.084580525973493 5.1367251129565776, 52.0845936126653 5.1367018828692963, 52.084593039704487 5.1366802926640958, 52.084593520236 5.1366613829106731, 52.084592797560617 5.136602794053033, 52.0845930285151 5.1365417347624449, 52.084591784281656 5.1365062294062227, 52.084592622431977 5.1364672367903337, 52.084591892315075 5.1364289335906506, 52.084595442516729 5.13633631542325, 52.084596794845957 5.1363224481129421, 52.084599652094766 5.13625919749029, 52.084600140111739 5.1362545876124468, 52.084603969780289 5.1361925578721053, 52.084604394622147 5.1361672168131918, 52.084607248043845 5.1361305358165161, 52.084609296828042 5.13606852098146, 52.084609103156254 5.1360535530839115, 52.084611643842678 5.1360064989442122, 52.08461217648793 5.1359452261162533, 52.084612038685009 5.1359415214974433, 52.084614087827504 5.1358594063203782, 52.084640604443848 5.1355516116600484, 52.084642857778817 5.135543460957706, 52.084982043160878 5.1354961035347806, 52.085083917947486 5.1345288194715977, 52.085104202153161 5.1343492493033409, 52.08524441709433 5.1330996853375064, 52.085165794240311 5.1330994283780456, 52.085158604676472 5.1330777355575146, 52.084887840552256 5.1328501671087, 52.084870130718066 5.1327825202649118, 52.084810143569484 5.132734818616882, 52.084766256157309 5.1326845148578286, 52.084753367166229 5.1326649976350005, 52.084720281418413 5.1326657184399664, 52.084673544857651 5.1326567681971937, 52.084627489326522 5.13263783371076, 52.084616634761915 5.1326309095602483, 52.084607382304966 5.1326056816615164, 52.084589018020779 5.1325388213153929, 52.084566780831665 5.1324195361230522, 52.08455663616769 5.1322953840717673, 52.084555578185245 5.1322289216332138, 52.084558193339035 5.1321669477038085, 52.084565328201279 5.1320932512171566, 52.084573237691075 5.1320388016756624, 52.084590001497418 5.1319514436181635, 52.084614846622571 5.1318454830907285, 52.084674907008818 5.1317076328407039, 52.084733415627852 5.1315451303962618, 52.084768428234277 5.1314570531469457, 52.084772500442341 5.131445026723668, 52.084790059469135 5.1313976899708305, 52.084790684864267 5.1313653332182225, 52.084789962507784 5.1313581170979887, 52.084786229995423 5.1313093374080232, 52.084781658835709 5.1312665985897183, 52.084776584757492 5.131205978570506, 52.084776126593319 5.1311985920700378, 52.084773858077824 5.1311737054493278, 52.084770929767942 5.1311195062007151, 52.084764682454988 5.1310441740788519, 52.084762406875207 5.1310067452953634, 52.084759807214141 5.1309909871779382, 52.084745739819482 5.1308908765204251, 52.084737451048568 5.1308199469931424, 52.084731393493712 5.1307550501078367, 52.084726219235463 5.130682019587562, 52.084717591805187 5.130595849588774, 52.084696356672794 5.1304316397290677, 52.084744368912652 5.1304192959796637))', 1) );
insert into #Shapes (naam,  shape) VALUES ('Area B', Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((52.089193944586441 5.1364884474314749, 52.089683880347387 5.1369394774090678, 52.090064640389755 5.1368089618626982, 52.090064767515287 5.13680902402848, 52.090108351781964 5.1372362461406738, 52.0900023451254 5.137240494616317, 52.089941830607358 5.1372731845887953, 52.089884013120034 5.1373362265352416, 52.089867649300196 5.13736428650584, 52.089863897534087 5.1374888976570219, 52.089852973818779 5.1375768855214119, 52.089850827719964 5.1375869208953633, 52.08984444080243 5.1376464707614575, 52.089846089016071 5.1376523461555816, 52.089855048116348 5.13767090524721, 52.089885986401136 5.1377142074887443, 52.089973680692943 5.137785122508185, 52.090167043032125 5.1378114717081189, 52.090184094849974 5.1379786091856658, 52.090212659211829 5.138269433286041, 52.090046387117965 5.1383854977954284, 52.089997038751484 5.1384536319841185, 52.089986001565585 5.1384773087642488, 52.0899993844796 5.138537187827751, 52.090003677353721 5.1385827515141784, 52.0900126749184 5.1386172289494425, 52.090020956756526 5.1386840232833055, 52.0900247762911 5.1386965326964855, 52.090037737332914 5.1387801609122805, 52.090253500966355 5.1393869426101446, 52.090253373142332 5.1393870580941439, 52.09018895904866 5.1393668668649326, 52.09019982968524 5.1394877681651483, 52.090232462748588 5.1397292593531256, 52.090305473417473 5.1400441225035083, 52.090441768325739 5.1400458008552627, 52.0905898406636 5.1397357748355716, 52.090624607168138 5.1397489595692605, 52.090674059544682 5.1398083794509937, 52.090694529374325 5.1397384163970843, 52.090704163346672 5.1396187301667995, 52.0906239267189 5.1386488468750029, 52.090564216952771 5.1380289690569043, 52.090701825218275 5.138007998932153, 52.090686907175666 5.1381677433547006, 52.090704979235063 5.1382210930865915, 52.090742795495316 5.13826614478603, 52.090745454392028 5.1382716438933382, 52.090780634433031 5.138317345874384, 52.090777151606311 5.1383238151729582, 52.090758565347642 5.1383729032240808, 52.090745967798135 5.1383894728374937, 52.090718918413778 5.1384487237036574, 52.09071148235433 5.1385074989634694, 52.090739235906476 5.1386199161658359, 52.091703911079094 5.1383786785881966, 52.091774561209604 5.1390583219472319, 52.091763966455993 5.1391488551129392, 52.091713952366263 5.1397284283302724, 52.091654634801671 5.1401592225302011, 52.091534660555041 5.1407988700928273, 52.091924405223438 5.1407296329252166, 52.092023730557614 5.1405292234111544, 52.092084533682055 5.1403785903667165, 52.092164086876437 5.1401694919914007, 52.092214212752879 5.1400685210246593, 52.092354092746973 5.1398882211651653, 52.092737518250942 5.1397820895072073, 52.092756280866688 5.1398568955139261, 52.092979332917338 5.1401287692562034, 52.093051998862443 5.14014675848039, 52.093115186976668 5.1400825616937738, 52.093306944705546 5.1395597066730261, 52.093307103263214 5.139559774659574, 52.093311476645688 5.1395944439214718, 52.093552575019729 5.1397174675798443, 52.093717376162488 5.1397005364784905, 52.093728081547653 5.1396937158987059, 52.093731097411364 5.1396904007997364, 52.093789641978219 5.1396499255206436, 52.09379703433958 5.139647218074332, 52.093849730910733 5.139608321711421, 52.0938674450952 5.1396007388582916, 52.093911277158938 5.13956686834194, 52.093702596845105 5.1390791060402989, 52.094214342534542 5.1384887341409922, 52.094234085874632 5.1384696427267045, 52.094364419566851 5.1384893088412067, 52.094364145770669 5.1383595434017479, 52.094394268468022 5.1381287302356213, 52.09443390479516 5.138148912037261, 52.094484106955747 5.1381194878988437, 52.094514668919146 5.1380682252347469, 52.094674076435417 5.1382088991813486, 52.095094393635229 5.1384881954232995, 52.0952940530714 5.1385585838544232, 52.095604252303019 5.1385889891535044, 52.095554116032766 5.1386696371579523, 52.095534724403237 5.1388492132525849, 52.095524277190037 5.1390082753444624, 52.095594465266913 5.1390487975440919, 52.095594199141487 5.1393494226504117, 52.09559461963309 5.1399783839006, 52.095604153974683 5.1410990775805754, 52.095644179129778 5.1413294123732438, 52.09575448022224 5.1416396433487535, 52.095824270925078 5.1419194503811445, 52.096084321906162 5.1429293346052836, 52.096143952025322 5.1430793148784755, 52.096264120657 5.1433793206233531, 52.096193926805284 5.1433798011214318, 52.096113997035054 5.14339920294765, 52.096024247104872 5.1434492955148228, 52.095944452364236 5.1435387324349744, 52.095874538511147 5.14362958598761, 52.095844099589421 5.143679338650661, 52.095844470186279 5.1438587997111922, 52.095854729064243 5.1440396906996444, 52.095894579105732 5.1441883100385768, 52.095964113250375 5.144369007088244, 52.09580374216273 5.144229786732418, 52.095674295010134 5.1441983953353239, 52.095563816432822 5.14421941922198, 52.095403983902024 5.1442888717546564, 52.095254029380158 5.1443597327452153, 52.094414402963594 5.1447291097138077, 52.094194360597214 5.1448091029165, 52.093554132385179 5.1451087987516075, 52.09298392268829 5.14536870829761, 52.092384074527615 5.1456389861371825, 52.091314621968991 5.1461291963244005, 52.091214230906282 5.1462493549551356, 52.091174073517323 5.1464188823010772, 52.0911739426665 5.146418813848868, 52.09113409327086 5.1462687528401041, 52.091084660668564 5.146199182483377, 52.091033940669149 5.1464488115161657, 52.090953806928624 5.1464084108564867, 52.090854425442245 5.1464496781230418, 52.089684411417693 5.1471287335734814, 52.0895846124041 5.1471190678897267, 52.088994233263378 5.1476095448153067, 52.088864096673205 5.1477386702317744, 52.088784483494237 5.1475289191585034, 52.088713807872537 5.1472491544173726, 52.088664193741309 5.1471487923554067, 52.088594123489734 5.1471287621828763, 52.088524112701435 5.1471597642893574, 52.088323859963566 5.1472586041782051, 52.088194384938106 5.1472490853630006, 52.088083737995476 5.147229231428355, 52.087984558660537 5.1470896604005247, 52.0871439545881 5.144788873847574, 52.086584153570342 5.1431184258301306, 52.086113808001116 5.1425490758657, 52.085764196002856 5.142129332292825, 52.085273851326242 5.1414594290601263, 52.084604130359367 5.1405483337584883, 52.08448414108716 5.1403388837352395, 52.084363697096705 5.1399091542698443, 52.084215331124142 5.1393728284165263, 52.084534444796994 5.1391156225659822, 52.084510998101905 5.1389506384730339, 52.084537685041475 5.1385358115798789, 52.084483979582181 5.1385094355204064, 52.084454281721264 5.138519779080525, 52.084444217151031 5.1384497005492449, 52.084904137838336 5.1374696237373572, 52.08508396637626 5.1370586035773158, 52.085304709049147 5.1372689084542849, 52.085683944402767 5.1372594968589222, 52.08695387118496 5.1372188439127058, 52.087364651495307 5.1372282228088277, 52.087484228890389 5.137229019543156, 52.087544555542991 5.1372593543492258, 52.087933897256818 5.1377590987963755, 52.088324117939919 5.1382486345246434, 52.088394418613781 5.138369242607296, 52.088414155179635 5.1383487726561725, 52.0884645585902 5.1383689332287759, 52.0884744236222 5.1383891381781037, 52.088854240353591 5.1373994332191018, 52.089193944586441 5.1364884474314749))', 1) );
insert into #Shapes (naam,  shape) VALUES ('Area C', Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((52.081104027922265 5.1258389879949391, 52.081314665614627 5.1259588550310582, 52.082414517994039 5.1266395719721913, 52.082954646321014 5.1270186660112813, 52.083513987367041 5.127549389610067, 52.083794155623764 5.1278395495610312, 52.084174386574887 5.1282589976908639, 52.084274505455781 5.1284189013796713, 52.08453426125925 5.1288288246141747, 52.085124507819643 5.1299386160409242, 52.08521465482071 5.1300693768952019, 52.0853342462746 5.1301182725468744, 52.0854241597699 5.1300988405710086, 52.0854743384989 5.1304488354362547, 52.085234220619661 5.130419600171515, 52.084744388967557 5.1304194940048324, 52.08439406089019 5.1305090384557843, 52.083914360133932 5.1306285039224422, 52.083414051565342 5.1307787221157923, 52.082813916262239 5.13094844610896, 52.082724283281529 5.1306586048111562, 52.082483787322417 5.1300093204481527, 52.08225411306649 5.1293789464909949, 52.082194455789093 5.1292188489812043, 52.082134172902443 5.1291885531973094, 52.082084508962 5.1290896165883169, 52.082023798371665 5.1288696515839547, 52.081883911043406 5.1281993770971894, 52.081856097793207 5.12798699515406, 52.081856237724423 5.1279869175050408, 52.082000762340613 5.1280515332473442, 52.082027135184035 5.1280940270517021, 52.0820355968099 5.1281161647869, 52.08205282002023 5.1281410993754166, 52.08213594150827 5.1278323108932256, 52.0820438895719 5.1277594091965328, 52.081953932996839 5.1277496579568833, 52.081884289887846 5.1271693162703134, 52.081813924670755 5.1270196131258938, 52.081552422139794 5.1268787173321471, 52.08152364961375 5.1267665265884057, 52.081485387952739 5.1266524291002371, 52.081442847483068 5.1265567842247837, 52.081396028901857 5.1264795880384764, 52.081344932177927 5.1264208389159505, 52.081293396464417 5.1263833287749234, 52.081279310281388 5.1263776289997622, 52.081249886541627 5.1263603481929749, 52.081222431567454 5.12633884719625, 52.081221418222412 5.1263384295161813, 52.081197269726545 5.126324187265709, 52.081195053295232 5.1263138890499249, 52.081184833077714 5.1262332251062617, 52.0811841667945 5.1261982778874859, 52.081168951815926 5.1261331316782162, 52.081164751928249 5.1260440781433525, 52.081066497950815 5.1259329431923106, 52.081104027922265 5.1258389879949391))', 1) );
insert into #Shapes (naam,  shape) VALUES ('Area D', Geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((52.084103860426694 5.1389694481622428, 52.084363892148971 5.1399091025981294, 52.084484331319835 5.1403388143996294, 52.084604299141489 5.1405482272725367, 52.08527401345782 5.1414593127556145, 52.085764355740025 5.1421292096101565, 52.086113962111995 5.1425489480607212, 52.086584335425869 5.1431183374952525, 52.087144145466013 5.1447888108543749, 52.087984736636635 5.1470895681108679, 52.088083857744529 5.1472290623707631, 52.088194406595086 5.14724888795369, 52.088323822820605 5.1472584035787792, 52.088524032849818 5.14715958177112, 52.088594117900357 5.1471285563893616, 52.08866433496587 5.1471486398950219, 52.088713997742161 5.1472490890882909, 52.088784678140655 5.1475289016962051, 52.088534413350153 5.1477695436890123, 52.088604030199349 5.1479895326774567, 52.08846407078854 5.1481186849763318, 52.088304384844378 5.1482683648355305, 52.087993860917578 5.1484991029959017, 52.087834112113342 5.1486196045298129, 52.0874739959836 5.1487791088875383, 52.087183827068657 5.1488594498950988, 52.087034655727216 5.1488792099405627, 52.086844170233235 5.1489094072021544, 52.086553779430687 5.1488890685141087, 52.086283983197063 5.1488190072122961, 52.086004210880986 5.148699401849246, 52.085884556407109 5.148648968199268, 52.085783737245947 5.148579464526847, 52.085444359574467 5.1483186569530517, 52.08505431888625 5.147909271530807, 52.085063869832084 5.14774867403321, 52.085103993769735 5.1475894195027649, 52.085123664481678 5.1475485048696683, 52.084903807879783 5.1472594002206034, 52.084644382136524 5.1469792136778958, 52.08418409107253 5.1464885615278035, 52.0837237383239 5.1459687419701368, 52.083234543621856 5.145409702023275, 52.082664410911732 5.1448292277490495, 52.082063829526305 5.1443087360821664, 52.082091124779964 5.1440836547198483, 52.081992223858833 5.1440890550147742, 52.08196270884946 5.14405638189055, 52.081944186007604 5.1439888756722212, 52.08194406144986 5.1439872064089114, 52.08192484639585 5.1439289392437786, 52.081920254660311 5.1439031759941996, 52.081906982464716 5.1438652367796749, 52.081898384261621 5.143827152704362, 52.081886463514792 5.1437939475605585, 52.081860758494884 5.143810536588699, 52.081833417158236 5.1438379039788957, 52.081759569933638 5.14407270308584, 52.0816137263635 5.1439596123534246, 52.081454453474372 5.1438598307431391, 52.081304313847795 5.14384896773845, 52.080264462672268 5.1430187125121805, 52.079664091113955 5.1425989381968975, 52.079524534521624 5.14249899610877, 52.079534315969795 5.1424492821097374, 52.079674492839317 5.1419992103874552, 52.079703816364884 5.1418385940623406, 52.079714205814525 5.141648898134008, 52.079727753764018 5.1414623958989978, 52.080252137147674 5.1417998058748831, 52.08029427562046 5.1417563394152745, 52.080314928898588 5.1417286938522011, 52.0803562682122 5.1416860464960337, 52.080404439009726 5.1416505186352879, 52.080450373701751 5.1416298456024379, 52.080458209152553 5.1416284950795994, 52.080495744477957 5.141600257018581, 52.080541761592031 5.141581037081778, 52.080577370766676 5.1415776146752092, 52.080586124956035 5.1415745182313319, 52.080565002281219 5.1411468000151217, 52.080635850084946 5.1411388639826328, 52.081214110314008 5.1410789246463136, 52.081586783519015 5.1409964717458934, 52.081614242866635 5.1412574960850179, 52.081570835318416 5.1413511682767421, 52.08156742547277 5.1413547724810877, 52.081523078051127 5.1414396720759816, 52.081520885843375 5.1414458907124478, 52.0815235725604 5.1414493722841144, 52.081564587075263 5.1415304632391781, 52.081586116692051 5.1416122366208583, 52.081591385416651 5.1417623861789625, 52.081744097638875 5.1417384068481624, 52.081754462670077 5.14239915706246, 52.081888611945665 5.1424242914485125, 52.081887235166505 5.1422738104593009, 52.081907565006986 5.1422072551213205, 52.081948822597042 5.1421398329548538, 52.081990273194968 5.1420943139491024, 52.082000561989844 5.1420720012392849, 52.082041298272088 5.1420040489174426, 52.08205503895892 5.1419854623652519, 52.082057312844228 5.1419532595345077, 52.082057383609936 5.141936854692176, 52.082061406905325 5.1418724298121266, 52.082061399472877 5.1418698709458113, 52.082065169426741 5.1418023992023132, 52.08206505025737 5.1417857583146542, 52.082067978335544 5.1417265709023923, 52.082068552136519 5.1417210444026873, 52.08207146529282 5.1416510321596576, 52.082074348499624 5.1415691960222105, 52.082074102712795 5.1415587870869786, 52.082077217031589 5.141500341455882, 52.082077142713729 5.1414836310842942, 52.082064611044075 5.1414689618560345, 52.08204338257201 5.1414488023146987, 52.0820095549712 5.1414023755017455, 52.08195383178483 5.1413428048418419, 52.0819458400365 5.1413370133377612, 52.081897551489291 5.141270585100548, 52.081845151958987 5.1412304241675884, 52.081783577566966 5.1409387167077512, 52.082063805446388 5.1408189585007031, 52.082534100375206 5.1404983382591407, 52.082604082068428 5.1404395992867649, 52.082693810134288 5.1403690781753832, 52.083284175475136 5.1398683352445742, 52.083963928950048 5.1391394941752653, 52.084103860426694 5.1389694481622428))', 1) );

select naam, shape, shape.Reduce(0.001) as reducedShape from #Shapes

drop table #Shapes
```

This returns two sets of polygons. First the unreduced set:

[image]

Then the reduced set:

[image]

These shapes are much simpler and they do have the rough shape correct, but what I would want is to have the border-parts still shared. So they have to be reduced together, in a way.

I think you have to break them up into polylines first (from edge to edge), then Reduce the lines and then reassembling them to polygons again. I have no idea how to do this in T-SQL though.

Any ideas?

*Edit:* 
I've accepted alphadaogg's answer. Both current answers weren't entirely covincing to me, but alphadogg has certainly put in the most effort and I really appreciate any sharing of thoughts. So the bounty goes to him.

I will follow-up with a self-answer later if I find a satisfying method.

**Follow-up**: I e-mailed with Isaac Kunen, Program Manager on the SqlServer Geo team. His helpfull response is below:

> Your problem is not at all rare, but
>   it isn't something we directly
>   support: it's an operation that
>   requires knowledge of the topology of
>   your figures, and we don't have
>   anything like this built in. 
>   Essentially, you don't want to store
>   separate polygons for each
>   neighborhood.  Rather, you want to
>   store curves representing portions of
>   boundaries, and reuse these boundaries
>   for multiple polygons.  When you
>   generalize, you generalize the shared
>   boundary, and all dependent polygons
>   are affected.
>
> You could build this yourself---as the
>   posters in the thread you cite
>   hint---but it may be real effort to do
>   so.
>
> I don't know the third-party software
>   you're using, but this is the other
>   option.  If you don't want a
>   full-fledged GIS, you could use a
>   package like the FME from Safe
>   Software (http://www.safe.com).  The
>   FME doesn't do general-purpose
>   topology, but I believe it has enough
>   functionality to do what you're
>   looking for.  See:
>   http://www.safe.com/products/desktop/under-the-hood.php#3b.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> Cheers,
>
> -Isaac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd get the "shared" LineStrings from your shapes. Secondly, once you reduce a "subset" of the shape since your endpoints may move from the original and you will not be able to make them match up after reduction.

The nutshell of what I would do is basically use boolean operations to play with the reduced shapes.

First, do what you do, namely create a temporary table of reduced shapes (called `#ReducedShapes`).

Then, I would create a second temp table and find the areas of overlap (using `STIntersection`) between all shapes. In this table, I would basically have columns `naam1`, `naam2` and `intsec`, the last one being of type shape. Something like (untested):

```
INSERT INTO #IntSecs(naam1, naam2, intsec)
SELECT s1.naam, s2.naam, s1.naam.STIntersection(s2.naam)
FROM #ReducedShapes s1, #ReducedShapes s2 
WHERE s1.naam.STIntersection(s2.naam) IS NOT NULL
```

This gets you a list of where pairs of shapes overlap. In fact, you have two rows for each overlap. For example, if A and B overlap you'd have  and . I would make a pass and delete one of the two for each occurence.

Lastly, for each overlap, I would subtract (`STDifference`) the intersection **from only one of the two** regions in the pair from the `#ReducedShapes` table. Imagine you have two squares A and B, half-overlapping. The operation would involve A.STDifference(B) meaning you keep all of B and half of A. I would insert the modified shapes into a third table (say `#ModifiedShapes`).

Two problems: 
a) as you can see from your "orange" and "blue" shapes, they did not reduce similarly, so you'll get one of two possible reductions depending on how you deal with who "wins".
b) a more complicated form of the problem is that, depending on the complexity of the initial shapes, you may get overlap between three or more regions. You'll have to determine your own way to establish which one shape "wins" in that intersection, based on your particular needs. It's not clear if there are constraints. Could be as simple as arbitrarily picking a winner by ordering, or more complicated since accuracy is important.

The above concept unfortunately does not address the issue of gaps. This one's a little more complicated and I am not 100% sure how to resolve it. But, if you create a third table that subtracts (`STDifference` again) all the modified shapes `#ModifiedShapes` from all the original shapes in `#Shapes` (testing for overlap before actually subtracting, of course), you'd be left with the remainder shapes in the gaps. You'd want to aggregate the adjoining shapes and assign a "winning color", possibly merging it back in with the related shape.

This answer is long and I will leave it like this. I may be barking up the wrong tree. Based on your feedback/questions, I would add to the post.

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. A different approach from what I had in mind. Very interesting. The problems with gaps and multiple overlaps are serious though. I think that "more than double overlaps" can be solved by adding the overlap always to the lowest ID shape. Gapsseems tougher.

Comment: Overlaps are hard because there are multiple ways to address them. But, I didn't know what your needs were. The easiest is to let one region win.

Comment: And, yes, gaps are much, much harder. The idea is to end up with a set of shapes for each gap, assign each one a color of a neighboring region and then merge it into that region. Not exactly sure how...

Comment: Maybe found it? Consider STInteriorRingN() on the STUnion() of all modded shapes. It should give you a GeomCollection of gaps. Then, armed with this list, find the areas in the gap from the original, unreduced shapes and pick a winner for each gap.

Comment: http://jasonfollas.com/blog/archive/2008/04/03/sql-server-2008-spatial-data-part-4.aspx

Comment: Yes, that could work. Although a gap might be "open ended". Haveing no bordering polygon on on side. There is no such case in the sample shown, but it could happen.

Comment: Actually, I think we've establsihed how to handle overlaps of reduced shapes. Now, you want to take care of the gaps inside your reduced shapes. If there is an "open gap", like a bay or indentation, then you don't really have to worry about it since it would stay as-is.

Comment: What could happen is that some inside gap is near the edge, such that it looks enclosed but isn't. Then, you'd have a bad inside shape. This would depend on your geo data's quality...

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that's a pretty cool set of features.

Taking a look at some of the other methods available, here are a few ideas that come to mind:

On the unreduced shapes, use .STIntersects (returns a boolean) and .STIntersection (returns a shape) to find out if and where two shapes intersect.

For two adjacent map regions, I would assume that .STIntersection should return the line segment that borders both.

Then you can reduce these line segments and re-assemble the reduced shapes.

Comment: Yes, I guess that STIntersection would be part of the solution. Also, taking STBoundary of A and intersecting it with B gives the shared border.

Answer (score 0):

Isaac is right that you could reduce the features to lines, and use them as shared boundaries.

But the software he mentions - FME - has a transformer called the Generalizer which will simplify them as you wish while still retaining them as polygons. The option to use is called 'Preserve Shared Boundaries'. You can download FME from [here][1] and request a 14-day eval license to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly speaking an answer to your question, but if your ultimate objective is to render maps in the browser, then you should look into Mike Bostock's TopoJSON project.

[image]

TopoJSON, like GeoJSON, is a javascript-friendly spatial file format. Unlike GeoJSON, TopoJSON contains just the topology so that shared borders are only represented once. This results in (a) more compact data and (b) seamless simplification.

There's a great introduction here, including live visualizations of the algorithm used to infer topology: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/topology/

The project wiki is here: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson